# Playing around with getopt

Tags: c++, getopt

Hi i'm pretty new to coding and trying to find why this getopt is not working. my compiler complains about "i:o:"

Error   C2664   'int getopt(int,char **,char *)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'const char [5]' to 'char *'

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'i':
            printf("Input file: \"%s\"\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'o':
            printf("Output file: \"%s\"\n", optarg);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which is weird since when i was reading about getopt i saw this "The options argument is a string that specifies the option characters that are valid for this program."

Comment: The third argument must be writable, string literals aren't writable. This may be a "code smell" in the getopt library you are using.

Comment: Which runtime are you using? I see `int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring);`

Comment: I'd suggest [Boost.Program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options.html) over `getopt`.

Comment: @FredLarson tried it. Not impressed.

Comment: What compiler?, OS? Your code works for me.

Comment: I'm running windows 10 microsoft visual studio 2017

Comment: I'm not aware of any `getopt` function in the Visual Studio libraries - which header did you include to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your error message the `getopt` function requires a *writable* options string. You could do that by making a non-const character array like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // non-const char array
    char opts[] = "i:o:"; // copy a string literal in

    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, opts)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'i':
            printf("Input file: \"%s\"\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'o':
            printf("Output file: \"%s\"\n", optarg);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

your original code works fine for me on `Linux` with `GCC v7`. It appears the function signature for the version you are using is different.

On **my** system it is:

```
int getopt (int argc, char** argv, const char* options);
```

But on your system it appears to be:

```
int getopt(int,char **,char *);
```

That lack of `const` on the last argument is causing the error which is why you need to give it a *non-const* string.

**Note:** I would not recommend using `const_cast` for this as some may be tempted. You never know how the function is implemented or if that internal implementation may change at some point.

Comment: If the implementation of `getopt()` really isn't modifying the options string, you could probably get away with using `const_cast`. But this sort of const correctness error suggests the library is outdated or poorly written.

Comment: Since `getopt()` will not write to the last parameter, you could `const_cast` the string literal instead of allocate a separate non-const buffer: `getopt(argc, argv, const_cast<char*>("i:o:"))`.

Comment: @FredLarson There is no telling how that function is implemented so I would never recommend `const_cast` based on probables and assumptions. Who knows? Maybe it uses `strtok`?

Comment: @Galik: I don't know where the implementation came from, since it's not a standard function and the OP is not on a POSIX platform. Source code might be available. If source is not available, you might be able to use a modifiable string as you suggest, then examine the string after the call to see if it was modified. Still some risk, though.

Comment: @FredLarson But implementations can change when you upgrade your libraries. So I am in the "just say no" camp. :)

Answer (score -4):

Just use a string pointer:

```
char* opts = "i:o:";
getopt(argc, argv, opts);
```

Comment: Which is not legal C++ either.  OP is mixing C and C++ and finding some of the differences.