confusing param type of getopt
So, man page says getopt() takes char * const argv[], which is an array of constant pointers to char, as far as I understand. At the same time, getopt() permutes argv, so that eventually all non-options are at the end of the array.
I find it very confusing, because it now has to swap strings character by character instead of just swapping pointers, or so. Why doesn't it take just char * argv[]?

It can't swap character by character, since the strings may not be the same length.

At the same time, getopt() permutes argv, so that eventually all non-options are at the end of the array.  That is not standard behavior - that's a GNU glibc extension.

https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/posix/getopt.c#L724 POSIX and LSB both require these functions to take 'char *const *argv'    even though this is incorrect (because of the permutation). I think you are right.

@KamilCuk It was char *const *argv way back in SUSv2, too

Relates   https://stackoverflow.com/a/49760047/7508077

From the man page for Linux:

Conforming To
POSIX.2 and POSIX.1-2001, provided the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set. Otherwise, the elements of argv aren't really const, because we permute them. We pretend they're const in the prototype to be compatible with other systems.

So you can omit the const qualifier on Linux.

So you can omit the const qualifier on Linux  But you can omit const anywhere for the array passed to getopt() - the const in the prototype is a promise that the function won't modify your array.  GNU's getopt() breaks const correctness.

Yes, apparently. But at least they own up to it.

I do find it strange that the behavior is dependent on an environment variable, not a feature-test macro.

I guess they don't want to own up to it too openly, though.  Else there would be something like #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE int getopt(int argc, char *argv[], const char *optstring); #else int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring); #endif in the header....

Note also that some versions of the man page don't have const, e.g. https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html

@Barmar See the VERSIONS section of that man page. const is used in the actual prototype to be compatible with other systems; however, this page doesn't show the qualifier, to avoid confusing readers.
